# Ada: How to read variable length strings from command line

Tags: string, command-line, ada

I am doing a multi-stack program with opcodes that look like the following:

```
I2 Sam
I3 Bobby
I1 Steve
D3
I3 Jonathan
```

"I" means insert and the number is which stack, "D" means to delete and number is which stack. My question is, how do I read each of these from the command line and determine which operation to perform? The names are of variable length, and I cannot use heap memory. The one thing I can do is, since the list of possible names is known, is make the names into an enumeration type. Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that you are referring to reading from Standard_Input when you say “command line”? The latter usually refers to that line consisting of the command's name and then any parameters passed to it. (package `Ada.Command_Line`)

Comment: probably, all I know is I run the program in the command line and need to gather the input while it is running, using "get(...)" is the only way I know how in terms of code @B98

Comment: You can read variable length strings to your heart’s content without using heap. What you can’t do is store them. You are probably right to consider an enumeration type; though it’s a _very_ fragile solution to the problem. The 'no heap' requirement is an artificial imposition (or perhaps you’re working on an MCU with only 1024 bytes of RAM?) (or have an anti-heap teacher!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are reading the values from standard input and are using at least Ada 2005, this method will work:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Foo is
   use Ada.Text_IO;
begin
   while not End_Of_File loop
      declare
         Cur_Line : constant String := Get_Line;
      begin
         -- process the line here
      end;
   end loop;
end Foo;
```

Comment: perhaps standard input meant a file? I am not reading from a file, but instead the keyboard at runtime

Comment: That's what standard input is. If you read a file, you would need to give `Get_Line` a handle to that file as argument. Without argument, it reads the standard input.

Comment: Oooh I see what you're saying, I didnt see the Get_Line had no argument, Thanks!

Comment: @Numnumberry: For convenience, you can save your ipnut in a file and feed it to `Foo` using your shell's I/O redirection, e.g. `./foo < file.txt`.